# Difference in these two CGContextShowTextAtPoint?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, pdf

When i `draw` these `text` in `PDF` to `truncate` to `specific width` difference in these two i don't get it.

**First One** :

```
NSString *strText12 = @"HASDHADH  skjdfhhs HKSJDHF.;; []'.hfkjhsfS SDHJHFSH jsfsjdfsn eiwj NJSDSJDF SDLKJJ sfkjsj wreoiwuowu 87243 7298 72jsdj h@#$$$!@$$";

if (strText12.length > 110 ) {
    strText12 = [strText12 substringToIndex:110];
    strText12 = [strText12 stringByAppendingFormat:@"...."];
}

CGContextSelectFont (aCgPDFContextRef, "Helvetica", 12, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (aCgPDFContextRef, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (aCgPDFContextRef, 0, 0, 0, 1);
const char *text1 = [strText12 UTF8String];
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (aCgPDFContextRef, 10,50.0, text1, strlen(text1));
```

**Second One** :

```
NSString *strText = @"hasdhadh  skjdfhhs hksjdhf.;; []'.hfkjhsfs sdhjhfsh jsfsjdfsn eiwj njsdsjdf sdlkjj sfkjsj wreoiwuowu 87243 7298 72jsdj h@#$$$!@$$";

if (strText.length > 110 ) {
    strText = [strText substringToIndex:110];
    strText = [strText stringByAppendingFormat:@"...."];
}

CGContextSelectFont (aCgPDFContextRef, "Helvetica", 12, kCGEncodingMacRoman);
CGContextSetTextDrawingMode (aCgPDFContextRef, kCGTextFill);
CGContextSetRGBFillColor (aCgPDFContextRef, 0, 0, 0, 1);
const char *text = [strText UTF8String];
CGContextShowTextAtPoint (aCgPDFContextRef, 10,10.0, text, strlen(text));
```

**Result in PDF** :

[image]

**EDIT** : Even using `CoreText` `result` is `same`.

Comment: I don't understand the question. You truncate both string to 110 *characters*. The upper case letters "HASDHADH" are *wider* than the lower case letters "hasdhadh", therefore the first string takes more space.

Comment: how would be able truncate string to specific width with depending string might any case letters in osx?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution can be : Get `no` of `upperCase letters` from `actual string` and now `proportionally` multiply with 35% of count which will be removed from `original index` which is 110.

```
NSString *textToDraw = some string
int range = 100;
NSString *strTruncate = textToDraw;
if (strTruncate.length > range ) {
    strTruncate = [strTruncate substringToIndex:range];

    //NSLog(@"now : %@",strTruncate);

    int actualIndex = 0;
    int count = [self getNoUpperCaseCharWithString:strTruncate];
    if (count>0) {
        float minusIndex = (float)count*0.35;
        actualIndex = range - (int)minusIndex;
        //actualIndex -= 4;
    }
    else{
        actualIndex = range;
    }

    if (strTruncate.length > actualIndex ) {
        textToDraw = [strTruncate substringToIndex:actualIndex];
        textToDraw = [strTruncate stringByAppendingFormat:@"..."];
    }

    //NSLog(@"after : %@",textToDraw);
}
```

Get `count` of `upperCase` letters from `string` :

```
-(int)getNoUpperCaseCharWithString:(NSString *)string
{
  int count=0;
  for (int i = 0; i < [string length]; i++) {
    BOOL isUppercase = [[NSCharacterSet uppercaseLetterCharacterSet] characterIsMember:[string characterAtIndex:i]];
    if (isUppercase == YES)
        count++;
  }
  return count;
}
```

**EDIT** : not found accurate solution to these.......